# How to get Selected option value from html:options collections

Tags: javascript, struts

I am having an Drop down in Struts. How  to get selected value from `<html:options>` tag in JavaScript?

```xml
<html:select property="temp_Id"  >  
<html:options collection="listmap" property="key"/>  
</html:select>
```

Comment: I want selected value In script

Answer (score 0):

Change your tag to

```
<html:select property="temp_Id" styleId = "tempId" >
html:options collection="listmap" property="key"/>  
</html:select>
```

Add the following in your java script

```
var e = document.getElementById("tempId");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
```

This should do.Thanks.

Comment: Attribute id invalid for tag select according to TLD

Comment: Thanks ArunM. How can i get value of selected key from HashMap

Comment: The javascript will get the key only from the HashMap. Not sure what you are looking for.

Comment: I want to  Iterate through Hashmap and want value of selected Key

Comment: That sounds strange .. Why would you want to do that ? If you are okke to show the value as the label for the option then try this <html:options collection="listmap" property="key" labelProperty="value" />

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/33631/discussion-between-arunm-and-niraj-deshmukh)